# Servlet running under Grails

Tags: grails, servlets

How can I run a servlet (UploadAction from GWTUpload project) under grails? I've successfully added the servlet and use it from the web.xml file. However, I really want to wrap some logic around the doPost/doGet methods using the grails framework (gorm).

Can I just subclass the servlet as a Controller, maybe just instantiate the servlet in the controller and call init()? I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing that comes to my mind is:

- write a grails controller, instantiate the servlet (once, in the contstructor or in @PostConstruct) and call init()`
- map the controller method (via `UrlMappings.groovy`) to the url that your servlet would be mapped
- call `servlet.service(request, response)`.

It's a bit of a hack though. Another way is to get ahold of a spring (grails) bean in a filter applied to the servlet, with `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext())` and invoke the custom logic there.

Comment: I think I might like your second solution better, although what do you mean by a filter applied to the servlet? I wouldn't mind getting the bean from spring "by hand" and then invoking on it.

Comment: you map the filter to a servlet in web.xml: instead of `url-pattern` you specify `servlet` in the mapping